# Slots are not resetting after custom action is met

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I've created a custom action which is triggered with the default fallback intent and resets the slots and restarts the flow. However, it is not working as expected. Neither the slots are reset and neither the flow is restarted. The bot behaves abnormally after the fallback intent.

Action File:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from rasa_core.domain import Domain
from rasa_core.trackers import EventVerbosity

import json
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import datefinder
import datetime

from rasa_core_sdk import Action
from rasa_core_sdk.events import SlotSet
from rasa_core_sdk.events import UserUtteranceReverted
from rasa_core_sdk.events import AllSlotsReset
from rasa_core_sdk.events import Restarted

class ActionRestarted(Action):
    def name(self):         
        return 'action_restarted'   
    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        return[Restarted()] 

class ActionSlotReset(Action):  
    def name(self):         
        return 'action_slot_reset'  
    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        return[AllSlotsReset()]
```

Story File:

### fallback

- utter_unclear
- action_slot_reset
- action_restarted

**Software Versions**
Python- 3.6
rasa-core- 0.14.4
rasa-nlu- 0.15.0

I want ActionRestarted and ActionSlotReset to work after the default intent is met and reset the slots and restart the conversation.

Comment: can you post the imports of the action files please? What do the logs say?

Comment: @Tobias, thanks for reply. i have updated the code with imports. there nothing in log file once the fallback intent is triggered. log file has data till last successful flow.

Comment: but what is in the log of the action server?

Answer (score 1):

Rasa has a default action "action_restart" which should do what you wish. In your story that would look like

```
#fallback
-utter_unclear
-action_restart
```